# How to open Google Chrome with Java

Tags: java, macos

So im trying to make an auto typer right now all i want the program to do is open Google Chrome. Im on a mac so its not a .exe file. The name of the file is (Google Chrome.app) The space in the name confuses me. Heres my code

```
package com.mycompany.autotyper;

import java.awt.AWTException;
import java.awt.Robot;
import java.io.IOException;

public class AutoTyper {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws AWTException, IOException {
        String str = "Hello World!";
    
        Robot rb = new Robot();
    
        Runtime rt = Runtime.getRuntime();
        rt.exec("Google Chrome.app");
    

    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

For me it worked:

```
Runtime rt = Runtime.getRuntime();
        rt.exec("open -a /Applications/Google\\ Chrome.app");
```

My Google Chrome.app is currently present in /Applications folder.

Use `\\` for reading space of file name.

Comment: To explain this answer even more: `rt.exec("command")` executes the given command as if you were in the Terminal. Thus, you can copy-paste anything you do in the terminal into `rt.exec()`.

Comment: Wait so how do i find the pasth through terminal?

Comment: Well my path to Google chrome is...

Comment: /Users/compsci/Applications/Google\\ Chrome.app

Comment: But when i run this nothing happens. It just says code finished. I dont see chrome open?

Comment: Can you see if you can use `sudo open -a /Applications/Google\\ Chrome.app` within rt.exec() and see if it opens.